# Solving algebraic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$10.5x = 5.7x + 29.64$

I've never done anything like the above with two variables of the same on both side, I'm thinking of subtracting 29.64 on the other side but I don't know if I can add it to 10.5x

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Remember that you can do anything to either side of the equation so long as you do the same thing to both sides (so it preserves equality).  So try subtracting $5.7x$ from both sides.  You'll get:

$$10.5x - 5.7x = 5.7x - 5.7x + 29.64$$
$$4.8x = 0x + 29.64$$

And so now we're at:

$$4.8x = 29.64$$

How can you get $x$ by itself at this point?

Answer (score 0):

$$10.5x - 5.7x = 5.7x - 5.7x + 29.64$$
$$4.8x = 0x + 29.64$$
$$x = 29.64/4.8$$
$$x = 6.175$$